# Dynamic matrix structure in typescript angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to create a structure to show on page which will be matrix and dynamic. Here Dynamic means new rows and columns can be added from check box check list.

For this one I tried to create a class in typescript which holds two properties, one is name and other is items array.

```
export class MatrixDTO {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "";
    this.items = [];     
  }
  name : string;
  items :Array<number>;
  
}
```

and in component I am trying to create an array of MatrixDTO so that each array contains , a name and array of items further.

```
  mat : MatrixDTO[]= new MatrixDTO();
```

but I am getting following error in this case :

**Type 'MatrixDTO' is missing the following properties from type 'MatrixDTO[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mat : MatrixDTO[]= new MatrixDTO();
```

With that line you try to assign a single object to an array, which is the reason for the error. Examples you could write instead:

```
mat: MatrixDTO[] = [];
mat: MatrixDTO[] = [new MatrixDTO()];
mat: MatrixDTO = new MatrixDTO();
```

Comment: and now how I can add items in that MartrixDTO[] ?

Comment: Because when I am trying to add items like this this.mat[0].name="Basic Weight(lbs/3000ft)";
    this.mat[0].items.push(30);
    this.mat[0].items.push(35);
    this.mat[0].items.push(40);

    this.mat[1].name="Basic Weight(g/m2)";
    this.mat[1].items.push(34);
    this.mat[1].items.push(42);
    this.mat[1].items.push(69); I am getting error for second item adding in array not for first one ?